# How does Gradle handle redundant dependencies

Tags: gradle

If I have two dependencies in my build.gradle file that refer to group artifacts and both of these groups contain references to the same jar files, how does Gradle handle them? Does Gradle recognize the version difference between the individual jar files that make up the group and only select the one with the newest version when a compile is made or does it pick the one that is listed last in the build.gradle file? Example:

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'some-sdk-1', name: 'sdk1', version: '2.5'
   compile group: 'some-sdk-2', name: 'sdk2', version: '1.0'
}
```

In this example, some-sdk-1 might contain a jar called lib1-1.0.jar
In some-sdk-2, the same library is present but has a different version. For example lib1-2.0.jar

Which jar file is used?

Comment: You can run `./gradlew :dependencyInsight --dependency lib1 --configuration compile` (if you are on Windows replace `./gradlew` with `gradlew.bat`. You will see how the conflict is resolved by Gradle. By default you will see that lib1-2.0.jar (newest) is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the jar file is put inside the library (sdk).

You should manage the jar files as **transitive** dependencies.
It means that inside the pom file related to the sdk you have a dependency of the jar file.
In this case you can [check the doc:](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting_dependency_resolution.html#sub:version_conflicts)

> Gradle offers the following conflict resolution strategies:
>
> Newest: The newest version of the dependency is used. This is Gradle’s default strategy, and is often an appropriate choice as long as versions are backwards-compatible.
>
> Fail: A version conflict results in a build failure. This strategy requires all version conflicts to be resolved explicitly in the build script. See ResolutionStrategy for details on how to explicitly choose a particular version.

Instead if you are just putting the jar inside the sdk **without using a transitive dependency** (just the jar file inside):

> If you don’t use transitive dependency management, version conflicts are undetected and the often accidental order of the classpath will determine what version of a dependency will win.